# XPath selection of nodes that don't have a specific optional attribute

Tags: xml, xpath

I need to get to the first node in this XML structure to make some changes:

```
<root-node>
    <child mandatory="val">
        ...
    </child>
    <child mandatory="val" optional1="opt1">
        ...
    </child>
    <child mandatory="val" optional1="opt2" optional2="opt3">
        ...
    </child>
</root-node>
```

Notice that all children have a mandatory attribute which has the same value in all cases, plus one or more optional attributes. But if I do an XPath on `//root-node/child[@mandatory='val']` I'm worried I might get a reference to the other nodes as well, which I don't want to touch.

Is there any way to be more specific and exclude the nodes that have a certain attribute present in their structure?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following XPath will return `child` elements which have `mandatory` attribute equal to `val` and do not have `optional1` attribute defined:

```
//child[@mandatory='val' and not(@optional1)]
```

If you need only first element, then just add `[1]` to expression:

```
root-node/child[@mandatory='val' and not(@optional1)][1]
```